# Scanline algorithm: calculate x of edges

Tags: javascript, algorithm, graphics, scanline

I'm trying to implement the scanline algorithm in Javascript. It looks like my calculation of x is wrong as the lines are to short or to long.

These edges should be filled:

[image]

This is how my scanline code fills it:

[image]

My edge table has these fields:

```
et.push({
    Ymin: Ymin, // minimum Y of the edge
    Ymax: Ymax, // maximum Y
    x: Xmin, // X value of Ymin point; updated for every scanline
    dx: Xmax - Xmin, // Delta X
    dy: Ymax - Ymin // Delta Y
});
```

The new X after every scanline is calculated this way:

```
// aet is active edge table
if (aet[i].dx != 0 && aet[i].dy != 0) {
    // this is not a vertical edge
    var incr = aet[i].dy / aet[i].dx; // =1/(dx/dy) ... dx/dy=m
    if (aet[i].dy > 0) {
        incr = incr;
    } else {
        incr = -incr;
    }
    aet[i].x += incr;
}
```

What is wrong in this calculation?

Comment: The incremental value added to x on every scanline. My code doesn't calculate the absolute value of x.

Comment: Shouldn't `incr` be the other way round? You seem to be incrementing `x` for each `dy`, so you need `dx/dy`. That way, the condition to rule out lines with `dy` makes sense: you avoid dividing by zero.

Comment: Oh, thats much better (still not perfect). I thought: 1/m = 1/(dx/dy) = (1/1)/(dx/dy) = dy/dx ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't show the scanline algorithm proper, but is looks as if you wanted to treat all scanlines from `Ymin` to `Ymax`. `y` starts a `Ymin` and increases by one for each scanline.

Therefore, the `x` for each scanline should increase by `dx/dy`.

You probably don't need to adjust the sign. Instead, the sign of `dy` is either positive or negative:

```
m = dx / dy                               # slope of the line
x[y + 1] = x[y] + m * dy = x[y] + m       # dy == (y + 1) - y == 1
x[y - 1] = x[y] + m * dy = x[y] - m       # dy == (y - 1) - y == -1
```

You scan in `x` direction and hence rule out horizontal lines for which `dy == 0`. That also shows in your maths: You cannot divide by `dy` when `dy == 0`.

Comment: Thanks, did now simply this: aet[i].x += aet[i].dx / aet[i].dy; and it looks good.